# Error when trying to edit created Document with context.application.createDocument

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I am developing an office web addin, and running in Word Online.
I am trying to edit a document that I have created with `context.application.createDocument`. Here is the code:

```
   Word.run(function (context) {
        var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(base64);
        context.load(myNewDoc);
        return context.sync().then(function () {

            myNewDoc.body.insertText('Hello World!', 'Start');
            myNewDoc.open();
            return context.sync();

        });      
    });
```

I get this error at insertion of text / context.sync():

> GeneralException The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the
>   OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information. statement: var
>   body=v.body;

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This error is by design. On the newly created document, you can only call open methods. All others methods are not supported which means you can't operate the newly created document.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this? I don't find any remarks about limitations or use in https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/application