# Word addin, set filename

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

If one starts a blank file on Word you can usually see in the top bar a name such as "Document1", "Document2" and so on.

Yet, if you attempt to open a file using the Word JS API like this:

```
Word.run((context) => {
  context.application.createDocument(documentB64).open()
  return context.sync()
})
```

The top bar comes out like this:

[image]

No filename is set.

To set a filename/handle(?), I tried using the code given here [Office JS - Add customProperty to new document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50275496/office-js-add-customproperty-to-new-document) but that didn't help.

My addin is usually used in conjunction with another (VSTO) add-on and that add-on can't work properly with the documents opened by my addin and I believe the lack of a filename (/handle?) explains it to some extent.

Is there something I can do about this?

Thank you

Comment: You might also try adding a Title document property which will give a default save name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

If you're downloading the file from the Internet you can use an Office URI instead, which resolves the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't do this because the newly created document is just a temporary file and not saved. can you try to call the following code to make sure the newly created file is saved?

```
const documentCreated = context.application.createDocument(externalDoc);
 documentCreated.save();
 documentCreated.open();
```

Comment: This actually works around the problem, the issue is that it pollutes the Documents folder of the user. For now I've just instructed users to save the file themselves so the other add-on can operate normally.

Comment: will it help if the document.save() API doesn't autosave to the Documents folder but open a popup dialogue to ask the user to choose the file location?

Comment: Not really, as the the end-user might want to do some changes to the document before saving it. And if the user does not want to save the document the issue remains.
If I do `context.application.createDocument()`, and then insert the content into the document, the issue does not apply as the document is assigned a file name (per top-bar) "DocumentX", despite not being saved anywhere.
It would maybe help though if we would be able to configure the page settings (margins and so on) using the JS API. Then I could create a new document and completely recreate it from scratch with a "file name".